reorder group bar plot according to the Specie column
I want to make a group bar plot with ggplot. but i want to reorder the bar according to the specie, for example first bars belong to sp1 ,  sp2 and then sp3 should be shown in a decsending order in the graph.
So far I am able to plot the graph like this

but genotype belong to sp1 should come first sp2 second and then genotype belong to sp3.
I am using this code
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=reorder(Genotype, -var) , y=var, fill=Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width=0.85)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#4850CE','#D37A3E'),
                    labels = c("Control Temperature (CT)","Heat tress (HS)")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = var, ymax = var+e,colour=Treatment),
                width=0.75, position = position_dodge(0.85))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('#4850CE','#D37A3E'))+
  theme_bw() + labs(x=NULL, y=expression("a. weight"^~g))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, max(data$var+data$e), length.out = 6),
                     labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.01))+
  geom_text(aes(label = Genotype, y = 0),angle=90, hjust=0, size=3)+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "black", size=8, face="bold"),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour= "black"),
        axis.text.y =element_text(colour="black", size = 8),
        legend.position = c(0.8, 0.92), legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(4, 'mm'),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 8,face="bold"))+
  guides(colour = FALSE)




Genotype
Specie
Treatment
var
e




BGB094
sp1
CT
185.9406
44.7377


BGB095
sp1
CT
248.2271
44.7377


BGB097
sp2
CT
162.4696
44.7377


BGB001
sp2
CT
284.5522
44.7377


BGB011
sp3
CT
185.5353
44.7377


BGB048
sp3
CT
219.0846
44.7377


BGB094
sp1
HS
150.9137
44.7377


BGB095
sp1
HS
211.05
44.7377


BGB097
sp2
HS
123.8366
44.7377


BGB001
sp2
HS
247.2338
44.7377


BGB011
sp3
HS
149.6919
44.7377


BGB048
sp3
HS
184.7978
44.7377




The basic code you need is:
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  arrange(Specie, desc(var)) %>%
  mutate(Genotype = factor(Genotype, unique(Genotype))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Genotype, var, fill = Treatment)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')

Then add the other codes
